# How to remove the last "." from for loop print

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range (20):
    print(i, end='.')
```

my result is actually

```
0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.
```

is there any way or advise so that my print will be

```
0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19
```

Comment: It's almost always easier to use `join` than to print in a loop. 
 `print('.'.join(str(i) for i in range(20)))`

Comment: If you want to avoid a join you could use `print(*range(20), sep=".")` but that isn't useful outside of printing to a console

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
print(".".join(str(n) for n in range(20)))
```

That generates the numbers from 0 to 19 (inclusive), converts each one to a string, joins them together with `.` as a separator, then prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use the inline "if" statement.
`for i in range(20): print(i, end="" if i == 19 else ".")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get all elements but the last one. Let's say you have that string on the variable `my_str`, you could try:

```
my_str[-1:]
```